# "eth0" card broken and replaced => ClearCase installation becomes obsolete

Tags: clearcase

*"eth0"* ethernet card was broken. 
   It had to be replaced by a new one in a machine running RHEL v.6.3

After that ClearCase is not able to start up any more.

It seems that *"eth0"* ethernet address *(i.e. The first ethernet card the O.S. detects)* is used by ClearCase to establish the linux ClearCase *"hostid"* for that machine.

[There is no need to change any licenses, as the machine uses a near-by "license server", in the same LAN, to legally obtain from it a floating license].

But the problem is that **ClearCase instalation in that machine has become obsolete**. I thing i have two main options to sort it out:

A trivial way out is simply reinstalling ClearCase from scratch, and everything will be ok again. But i imagine there should be a more straightforward solution perhaps by changing the machine ID in some ClearCase configuration file instead or reinstalling everything ...

A second option is to use the responses from previous installation to reinstall automatically.

Can you help please which is the quickest way out ?

TIA, Javier.

Comment: Have you tried changing the mac address of eth0?

Comment: As @NickW said above, you can change the mac address by setting MACADDR in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.

Comment: Thanks NickW, lsd !!: I am checking that. Problem is i do not have the old address written down.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by become obsolete in this context... perhaps this might be a question for your vendor's support?

Comment: Thank you, Falcon. I mean that somehow its id for ClearCase changes and so the installation becomes obsolete, that is: invalid.  It has to be reinstalled again with the same procedure than before.    I simply hoped there was a shorter workaround than having to reinstall it.

Comment: ... , by adapting the previous installation to the new id.

Answer (score 2):

Licensed software on the Linux side generally uses the MAC address of eth0.  Changing the eth0 MAC address thus will cause a problem here.  I personally not fond of that particular licensing system since MAC addresses can be easily changed on any system VM or real these days and only offers illusionary protection to the vendor.